# Heroku App Crash err: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm doing the Hartl tutorial and my rails app works fine in development, but crashes in heroku with this error code:

```
application_controller.rb:5:in `<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper (NameError)
```

This happened after I added a remember_digest to the schema. Not sure if it's migrations or an issue between SessionHelper and ApplicationController

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

**Sessions_Helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

I tried deleting my old heroku app and starting a new one to reset the migrations (worked to "troubleshoot" in the past) but it didnt work this time.  All of the migrations are showing up when I ran `heroku rake db:migrate` except the remember digest one. I ran db:migrate again but can't get it to migrate.  Here are migrations:

**Migrate.db**

```
20150204074511_create_users.rb                  20150204093042_add_phone_number_to_users.rb
20150204081616_add_index_to_users_email.rb      20150204094519_add_index_to_users_phone_number.rb
20150204081750_add_password_digest_to_users.rb  20150207093225_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb
```

**Migrate logs**

```
ajhausdorf@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/AccessOBD (master) $ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4474
   (18.0ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying NOT NULL) 
   (8.6ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations"  ("version")
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateUsers (20150204074511)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
== 20150204074511 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   (15.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying, "email" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) 
   -> 0.0162s
== 20150204074511 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0164s) =============================

  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150204074511"]]
   (4.0ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to AddIndexToUsersEmail (20150204081616)
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
== 20150204081616 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating =============================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   (4.6ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_email" ON "users"  ("email")
   -> 0.0081s
== 20150204081616 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrated (0.0082s) ====================

  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150204081616"]]
   (5.5ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to AddPasswordDigestToUsers (20150204081750)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20150204081750 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
   (1.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "password_digest" character varying
   -> 0.0022s
== 20150204081750 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrated (0.0023s) ================

  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150204081750"]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to AddPhoneNumberToUsers (20150204093042)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20150204093042 AddPhoneNumberToUsers: migrating ============================
-- add_column(:users, :phone, :string)
   (1.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "phone" character varying
   -> 0.0023s
== 20150204093042 AddPhoneNumberToUsers: migrated (0.0024s) ===================

  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150204093042"]]
   (2.8ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to AddIndexToUsersPhoneNumber (20150204094519)
   (4.4ms)  BEGIN
== 20150204094519 AddIndexToUsersPhoneNumber: migrating =======================
-- add_index(:users, :phone, {:unique=>true})
   (7.5ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_phone" ON "users"  ("phone")
   -> 0.0110s
== 20150204094519 AddIndexToUsersPhoneNumber: migrated (0.0111s) ==============

  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1)  [["version", "20150204094519"]]
   (4.7ms)  COMMIT
```

How can I get this last migration to work?

Comment: Could you include the top of the ```sessions_helper.rb``` file?

Comment: @garythegoat no problem, its the second file included above

Comment: Are you referring to the Application Controller file? I'm asking for the entire code for the sessions_helper.rb file. You're missing the module definition which should be included at the top.

Comment: @garythegoat thanks for catching that. It should be correct now with the module definition.

Comment: where is the sessions_helper.rb file located?

Comment: @garythegoat app/assets/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that git wasn't tracking any of the sessions files I had added, so they were on my local computer but not on github->heroku. I found this out by making a change only on sessions_helper, then committing to git only to get a message that there were no changes to any files but several (all of the sessions files) were untracked.

Happened because I used git -am "commit message" rather than git add -A first bc I thought the -a flag added everything. Should've checked git to make sure sessions_helper.rb was there, all the answers told me to check this but I was only checking on my local machine.

Comment: Just saved me from a long session of head scratching!